# conflict with pst-tree and align: auto-pst-pdf problems?

Tags: pstricks, align, auto-pst-pdf, pst-tree

There appears to be a problem when using the pst-tree package together with the align environment and pdflatex (dvi-ps-pdf works, but there are reasons for me not to use it).
Attached is a code example using the equation environment, leading to the correct result. When changing in both equations \begin{equation} to \begin{align} the second equation shows the same picture as the first equation. This is definitely not correct.

Note that upon typesetting I get the message:

```
Package pst-pdf Warning: `test_tree-pics.pdf' contains 4 pages 
(pst-pdf)                but 2 pages are requested: 
(pst-pdf)                File `test_tree-pics.pdf' is no more valid! 
(pst-pdf)                Recreate it .
[1 
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
```

The file test_tree-pics.pdf appears to contains both figures twice.

Does anybody have suggestions? Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\newcommand{\TreeSpace}{0.7cm}
\newcommand{\RadiusMeagre}{3pt}
\newcommand{\RadiusFat}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ddot{u} = \pstree[treemode=U,levelsep=\TreeSpace,radius=\RadiusMeagre]{\Tc*{\RadiusMeagre}}{\TC *} \,\,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{p} = \pstree[treemode=U,levelsep=\TreeSpace,radius=\RadiusMeagre]{\Tc{\RadiusFat}}{\TC* \TC*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi Herbert, thanks for your quick response. unfortunately the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\PreviewEnvironment{align*}%% Make it known to preview

\newcommand{\TreeSpace}{0.7cm}
\newcommand{\RadiusMeagre}{3pt}
\newcommand{\RadiusFat}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\ddot{u} = \pstree[treemode=U,levelsep=\TreeSpace,radius=\RadiusMeagre]{\Tc*{\RadiusMeagre}}{\TC *} \,\,
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\dot{p} = \pstree[treemode=U,levelsep=\TreeSpace,radius=\RadiusMeagre]{\Tc{\RadiusFat}}{\TC* \TC*}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The `equation` environment is known by default but `align*`not.

```
[...]
\begin{center}
$\ddot{u} = \pstree[treemode=U,levelsep=\TreeSpace,radius=\RadiusMeagre]{\Tc*{\RadiusMeagre}}{\TC *} \,\,$

$\dot{p} = \pstree[treemode=U,levelsep=\TreeSpace,radius=\RadiusMeagre]{\Tc{\RadiusFat}}{\TC* \TC*}$
\end{center}
[...]
```

Comment: The pictures are correct, but there are no 'returns' present after the equations... so they are all on one line now (even when I put text inbetween).

Comment: add an empty line between the environments

Comment: hmm, it is still strange. now the equation numbers do not align anymore (I use align instead of align*).

Comment: that is a problem with the `preview`package. You can use `{\raggedleft ...}`. However, why can't you use simply `xelatex` and everything will be fine, without loading `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: ok, I didn't try that. I am not sure if it works with the classic thesis style that I use, and if it works in Texshop.

Comment: sure, it will work. The only difference is the definition of fonts, that's all

Comment: xelatex works for the example that I posted. but when using it for the classicthesis style I get ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. maybe off-topic...

Comment: difficult to say what's going wrong ...

Comment: it happens when hyperref is loaded as well. without hyperref it works like a charm.

Comment: I cannot believe that hyperef will increase the needed memory. However, you can also increase `main memory size=50...`

Comment: I'll try.. another issue with `xelatex` is that psfrag doesn't work anymore. Ideas?

Comment: ah ok, that is a problem. there is a `pdffrag` but I never used it.